# Rendering not working with MediaElement windows RT

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, render, mediaelement

I need to take thumbnail from Video playing with MediaElement

For this i learn there is [RenderTargetBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx) in windows 8.1 API

```
RenderTargetBitmap a = new RenderTargetBitmap();
await a.RenderAsync(myMedia);
thumb.Source = a;
```

and second way i got with help of **WinRTXamlToolkit.Composition** toolkit which do rendring with **WriteableBitmapRenderExtensions** class

```
WriteableBitmap w = await WriteableBitmapRenderExtensions.Render(myMedia);
thumb.Source = w;
```

Both these methods are working with all **UIElement** but not with **MediaElement**

only black screen is visible when  source this to Image object.

Can any one tell me why? and how can i take thumbnail from video?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the methods you mentioned might be limited in that regard. I'd still try RenderTargetBitmap but with something overlaid on top of the MediaElement. I believe if you place anything on top of a MediaElement, like a 0.01 opacity, 1x1 sized, black rectangle - it will switch to run in some different rendering mode where it is possible RenderTargetBitmap would be able to render it. Otherwise I think someone discussed here a while back a question of capturing a frame from a video stream. IIRC it is a pretty involved process though, involving using DirectX or Media Foundation and quite a bit of native code.

Comment: I just need to capture desired frame in windows store app, seems simple but can't do yet :(

Comment: Filip, that's a brilliant suggestion, let me try that out, will get back shortly!

Comment: @Filip No luck, even if you composite a Canvas with some Opacity on top of the Media element the content of the MEdia Element still isn't captured.