# MediaElement and RenderTargetBitmap - workarounds for app screen capture

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-10, uwp

Has anything changed regarding the `RenderTargetBitmap` and rendering of `MediaElement` frames on Windows 10 UWP? Previously that scenario wasn't supported, but it's clearly something people wanted to be able to achieve:

[Rendering not working with MediaElement windows RT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971111/rendering-not-working-with-mediaelement-windows-rt)

[How do you capture current frame from a MediaElement in WinRT (8.1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19871443/how-do-you-capture-current-frame-from-a-mediaelement-in-winrt-8-1)

If this scenario still isn't supported (and [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap) + my own samples seem to confirm these suspicions), are there any workarounds to do complete app window/screen capturing, with video frames and XAML and everything?

I am aware of the [ScreenCapture APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt282147.aspx) but for some strange reason those APIs work only on Mobile device family.

Comment: I don't think they'll ever add that, as MediaElement has bunch of DRM stuff built-in and they don't want to give you an easy way to circumvent it.